# Is it possible to lock the applying label option for a work_branch in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

But  check in/out & merge should happen for the same work_branch.The only aim is that work_branch should not allow applying any label.

Answer (score 1):

Since:

- locking the `brtype` for that branch would also prevent checkout/checkin,
- locking the `lbtype` would prevent any mklabel on *any* branch,

You can try instead definining a pre-op trigger on `mklabel`:

If that `mklabel` operation is done on the wrong branch, that pre-op trigger would exit with a non-zero status, preventing the `mklabel` to proceed and apply the label.
See [EV (Environment Variables) section of the mktrtype command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm).

See an example (not based on branches) [in this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013732789):

```
ct mktrtype -element -all -preop mklabel -exec "/path/to/script"
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually. You can also use a trigger with an inclusion list.

```
cleartool mktrtype -element -all -preop mklabel -brtype nolabel -exec "ccperl -e \" die();\"" NOLABEL_TRIG
```

Will block any attempt to make a label on a given brtype. Pardon the windows centric nature of the above.