# ClearCase apply preop checkin trigger script on each file

Tags: triggers, clearcase, checkin

I do have a script with check the format/style of the files. We used to run it on all elements every night using sort of night_script.

Now I want to add it to a preop trigger for checkin command. To do that per file(s) a switch is needed. How could I do so?

Example of how the script runs:

```
style_check -f file1 [file2 ... fileN]
```

I found this trigger creation command while searching but I don't know how to customize it :)

```
#execute a script on all text files after checkin:
ct mktrtype -element -all -preop checkin -eltype text_file -exec <path to script> PROCESS_CHECKIN
```

Answer (score 0):

See "[Is it possible to lock the applying label option for a work_branch in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48515768/6309)" for an example of preop trigger:

```
ct mktrtype -element -all -preop mklabel -exec "/path/to/script"
```

See also the Examples section of [`cleartool mktrtype`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm)

The trick is to use a shared path accessible by all ClearCase client workstations.

check the "[Trigger operations and trigger environment variables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm#ref_mktrtype_refsect1_234654)" to find the right variable to pass as parameter to your script: in your case, `CLEARCASE_PN`

```
ct mktrtype -element -all -preop mklabel  -execwin "\\path\to\script \"%CLEARCASE_PN\"" and -execunix "/path/to/script $CLEARCASE_PN"
```

Note the use of `-execunix`/`-execwin` to reference the same script (or a different script) per OS.

Comment: The quoting on the execunix and execwin clauses is wrong. It should be more like:
-execwin "\\path\to\script \"%CLEARCASE_PN\""
and
-execunix "/path/to/script $CLEARCASE_PN"

You may want to include quotes on the Unix side as well, although unix folks generally don't put spaces in filenames.

Comment: @BrianCowan Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.